# New piano flaking near hitch pin

Tags: piano, maintenance, repair

I recently purchased a new Yamaha C1X, and I noticed that the paint has started to flake off at various places after a few days, near the hitch pin (see picture).

This doesnt seem to affect the sound (yet), but just wanted to see if there are any piano technicians who might be able to advise if this is a common problem or not?

[image: Paint flaking near hitch pin]

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering what might cause that. Was the piano tuned in preparation for sale? Maybe the tuning wrench slipped and cracked the paint and it's only now coming off due to the vibration of being played?

Comment: The piano came straight from Yamaha UK, and probably had an preliminary tuning.I had suspected that the flaking was probably due to someone "seating the strings" too aggressively (after shipping, some technicians usually place a screwdriver and tap on the strings with a mallet after shipping).

When I contacted Yamaha, they suggested that this was "not normal", and asked me to raise a ticket via the retailer (Yamaha does not deal direct with customers). Retailer has now schedule a replacement.

Comment: I know this question is almost 2 years old. However, as both a mechanic and musician, I would be more annoyed than concerned about this defect. Japanese manufacturers have historically used inferior coatings (paint) on all of their products. The high resolution of this picture also suggests that the coating may have been applied too heavily and that the surface may not have been properly prepared prior to the application of the coating. THZP should post their resolution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this question was posted 2 years ago, but for any others, I hope this helps.

It happens to some Yamahas. It will not affect your sound. If you do not like the looks of it, you can contact https://ca.yamaha.com/en/support/contacts/index.html.
I hope this helps.